# using TWIG in IIS 7

Tags: iis, twig

I have a moto cms template requiring .twig mime type and I am hosting on a Windows server 2012 with IIS 7. I have Mysql and php 5.3.7 for the site. I need to have a .twig mime type and am looking for how to implement this in IIS. Sorry I am just a learner at this.

Comment: As far as I know you don't need to attach a handler to the  `.twig` extension.  `Twig` uses his own 'compiler' to generate `php` files from the `twig template` files. What is not working? Which errors do you get?

Comment: I have added a MIME type .twig text/css which seams to have resolved the problem. Thank you for looking in to it